# Can we find a simple formula for $N=N(ε)$

Tags: limits, prime-numbers

Let $(p_{n})_{n≥1}$ be the sequence of prime numbers. I know that $$\lim_{n→∞}(\ln(\ln p_{n}))/p_{n}=0$$

Then by the definition of the limit: given $ε>0$ there exist $N=N(ε)$ such that for all $n>N$ we have 
$$\ln (\ln p_{n})/p_{n}<ε \quad ?$$

My **question** is: can we find a simple formula for $N=N(ε)$?

Comment: For all $n>4/\varepsilon^2$, we have $\frac{\ln\ln p_n}{p_n}<\frac{2\sqrt{p_n}}{p_n}=\frac{2}{\sqrt{p_n}}\le \frac{2}{\sqrt n}<\varepsilon$.

Comment: @EdwardH. Can we find another sharper estimate for $n$.

Comment: Do you require $N$ to be the minimal such $N$? Otherwise we can just take any weak lower bound.

Comment: @YiFan: Yes, I want a minimal value.